# Difference between './path' and 'path' in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

Generally they work both okay for me and I rarely met the situations where they are different.

Today, when I try to load a customized defined module:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> encoding = tf.load_op_library('./ops/encoding.so')
>>> dir(encoding)
['LIB_HANDLE', 'OP_LIST', '_AggregateGradOutput', '_InitOpDefLibrary', '_ScaleL2GradOutput', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_aggregate_grad_outputs', '_collections', '_common_shapes', '_context', '_core', '_dtypes', '_errors', '_execute', '_op_def_lib', '_op_def_library', '_op_def_pb2', '_op_def_registry', '_ops', '_pywrap_tensorflow', '_scale_l2_grad_outputs', '_six', '_tensor_shape', 'aggregate', 'aggregate_eager_fallback', 'aggregate_grad', 'aggregate_grad_eager_fallback', 'scale_l2', 'scale_l2_eager_fallback', 'scale_l2_grad', 'scale_l2_grad_eager_fallback', 'tf_export']
```

They gives out different results.

```
>>> encoding = tf.load_op_library('ops/encoding.so')
>>> dir(encoding)
['LIB_HANDLE', 'OP_LIST', '_InitOpDefLibrary', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_collections', '_common_shapes', '_context', '_core', '_dtypes', '_errors', '_execute', '_op_def_lib', '_op_def_library', '_op_def_pb2', '_op_def_registry', '_ops', '_pywrap_tensorflow', '_six', '_tensor_shape', 'tf_export']
```

The `tf.load_op_library`:

```
Args:

    library_filename: Path to the plugin. Relative or absolute filesystem path to a dynamic library file.

Returns:

    A python module containing the Python wrappers for Ops defined in the plugin.
```

Since it is hard to search related questions by using keywords `./` and `python`, I am wondering whether you could give me some advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.load_op_library` calls the C function `TF_LoadLibrary`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py#L56). According to [the documentation for that function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3be04971716fcaf0c11ad9262e60efa428553e14/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1577-L1589):

> Load the library specified by library_filename and register the ops and kernels present in that library.
>
> **Pass "library_filename" to a platform-specific mechanism for dynamically loading a library. The rules for determining the exact location of the library are platform-specific and are not documented here.**
>
> On success, place OK in status and return the newly created library handle. The caller owns the library handle.
>
> On failure, place an error status in status and return NULL.

I think that the "platform-specific mechanism for dynamically loading a library" for your platform might not check the current directory, so you have to specify `./` in front of the filename to explicitly use the current directory.

Comment: Implementation note: On POSIX platforms, `TF_LoadLibrary` [just calls `dlopen`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9590c4c32dd4346ea5c35673336f5912c6072bf2/tensorflow/core/platform/posix/load_library.cc#L27). See [`man 3 dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html#DESCRIPTION) for how it resolves library names.